# Calling Artisan programmatically can't redirect with var

Tags: laravel

When calling artisan programmatically before the redirection this cause redirection to loose data.

Function in controller:

```
public function clearCache()
    {
        if ((boolean)Auth::user()->adminRights) {
            try{
                 Artisan::call('cache:clear');
                 Artisan::call('route:cache');
                 Artisan::call('config:clear');
                 Artisan::call('view:clear');
            }catch (Exception $e){
                return Redirect::route('admin.dashboard')->with('messages', $e->getMessage());
            }
            return Redirect::route('admin.dashboard')->with('messages', 'Cache is cleared!');
        }
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

When i comment the line of route cache messages contains again data.

```
//Artisan::call('route:cache');
```

How can i also cache route and then return messages to my redirection route?

Comment: `\Artisan::call('route:clear');` have you tried it?

Comment: Yes this works! But does not cache also the routes.

Comment: If you want to remove the routes cache on your server, remove this file:

`bootstrap/cache/routes.php`